# How to return the Resource Array from a ListView

Tags: android, arrays, listview

I have a ListView defined as follows:

```
<ListView
android:key="key1"
android:title="@string/title"
android:summary="@string/summary"
android:entries="@array/options"
android:entryValues="@array/values" />
```

The Entries & Values are specified in the XML file as you can see. How can I programmatically get the Array of the Entries from the ListView?

Something along the lines of this:

```
ListView myListView = this.findViewById(R.layout.my_layout);
String[] myListViewEntries = context.getResources().getStringArray( myListView.??????? );
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Please don't tell me to hard code an array name (like "R.array.some_array"), this must be done using the ListView object only, no hard coding of array names.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you may achieve this by calling `myListView.getAdapter()` which should return the adapter used to create list entries. By then you may add/edit/remove items from the adapter to further modify your list.

this is how you can retrieve your string array from adapter:

```
String[] array = getStringArray(myListView.getAdapter());
```

and your static method:

```
public static String[] getStringArray(ListAdapter adapter){
        String[] a = new String[adapter.getCount()];

        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
            a[i] = adapter.getItem(i).toString();

        return a;
    }
```

Comment: What method can you call form the Adaptor to return an array?

Comment: I see that it has a `getItem(int i)` method. Is there no method to return an array or must I loop through and manually create the array from all the items?

Comment: yes, you need to iterate through all items to create your own array. But still better than hard-coded, isn't it? :)

Comment: for more convenience, perhaps you may create a static method which takes adapter as parameter and returns string array, and reuse it whenever you want

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the elements from the adapter

```
ListAdapter adapter = ListView.getAdapter()
```

and then you can loop through all the elements

```
for(int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
    doSomethingWithElement(adapter.getItem(i));
}
```